# Цикл перезаписывает элемент массива вместо добавления

Tags: javascript, массивы

Не могу понять почему

```js
    var dateNum = {
        vlad: "September 18 2016",
        vania: "June 30 2016",
        vova: "August 5 2016",
        max: "May 10 2016",
        oleg: "December 15 2016",
        roma: "April 4 2016",
        tarasD: "April 17 2016",
        sergio: "February 23 2016",
        gambal: "May 10 2016",
        tarasG: "December 25 2016"
    };
    
    var today = Date.now();
    
    for (var key in dateNum){
        var remaining = Date.parse(dateNum[key]) - today;
        var readyDate = [];
        
        remaining /= 1000; // секунды до даты
        remaining /= 60;    // минуты до даты
        remaining /= 60;    // часы до даты
        remaining /= 24;    // дни до даты
        
        remaining = remaining.toFixed(); // зводимо до цілих значень
        
        readyDate.push(parseInt(remaining));
        
        console.log (readyDate);
        
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

var readyDate = []; постоянно обнуляется в цикле